# EXC_BAD_ACESS on importing a vcf vcard file

Tags: iphone, ios, exc-bad-access, abaddressbook, vcf-vcard

I am retrieving vcard data from a vcf file from the app documents directory into a String. The string is fine but `ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation` throws BAD_ACCESS error.
Heres the code...

```
ABRecordRef defaultSource = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
 NSData *data=[vcardString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
CFDataRef vCardData = (__bridge CFDataRef)data;
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
                if(granted)
                {
                    NSLog(@"%@",vcardString);
                    CFArrayRef vCardPeople = ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(defaultSource, vCardData);//BAD_ACCESS ERROR
                    for (CFIndex index = 0; index < CFArrayGetCount(vCardPeople); index++) {
                        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(vCardPeople, index);
                        ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, person, NULL);
                        NSLog(@"added");
                    }

                    CFRelease(vCardPeople);
                    CFRelease(defaultSource);
                    ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, NULL);
                }
                else
                    NSLog(@"not granted");
```

Heres the NSLog vcardString...

```
BEGIN:VCARD

VERSION:3.0

PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//iOS 6.1//EN

N:;Home;;;

FN:Home

EMAIL;type=INTERNET;type=HOME;type=pref:carljosdsdsewhnson.akasdssh@gmail.com

TEL;type=CELL;type=VOICE;type=pref:2323454645

PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=JPEG:/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAICAgICAQICAgIC

....LOT OF GIBBERISH....

END:VCARD
```

Comment: How are you making vCardData??

Comment: Ok sorry about that, next question...where are you making "defaultSource"?  I think you might need to recreate it *after* you get permission.

Comment: @borrrden edited again.

Comment: Try using `NULL` instead of `defaultSource` (the docs indicate that defaultSource will be used by default).

Comment: Nevermind that, I got what is going on.  `data` is being released and so `vCardData` is becoming a dangling pointer.  I will post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `CFDataRef` as required, but the memory management is out of whack.  The completion handler will not be executed in line, and by that time `data` will have been deallocated.  That makes `vCardData` a dangling pointer making a bad access.  To fix this, instead of `__bridge` use `__bridge_retained` and then call `CFRelease` on `vCardData` once you are done.

```
ABRecordRef defaultSource = ABAddressBookCopyDefaultSource(addressBook);
 NSData *data=[vcardString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
CFDataRef vCardData = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)data;
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
    if(granted)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",vcardString);
        CFArrayRef vCardPeople = ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(defaultSource, vCardData);//BAD_ACCESS ERROR
        CFRelease(vCardData);
        for (CFIndex index = 0; index < CFArrayGetCount(vCardPeople); index++) {
        //...
```